# Blazor app not running server code when on hosted server

Tags: .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor web assembly app and I have 3 projects that were created. The client, server and shared. I assume all of these are deployed as standard when using the webdeploy?

The site works in that it displays the pages etc. However when I go to a page that contacts the server project via the Http.PostAsJsonAsync() method, I get the blazor error page (which I setup to say "oops").

Obviously I get no details as to what is going wrong. So I have no idea what is happening. Is the server app compiled into the Web assembly app? If so why would it not be running the server code? Plus I suppose the other question is how do I get it to report the error so that I can get an idea as to what is going wrong?

It works absolutely fine when running it through Visual Studio.

This is the first time I have deployed to a hosted server so there is a very high chance I have done something wrong...

The method I am calling literally does nothing other than returning a 200 message. So I assume the issue is with calling the server method itself.

Comment: debug mode perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use Logging:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server

```
@inject ILogger<MyComponent> Logger
```

Then wrap your Http.PostAsJsonAsync() call in a Try Catch block.

Log the error in the Catch block:

```
try
{
     await Http.PostAsJsonAsync()
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.LogError(e);
}
```

After deployment, edit your web.config file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
            arguments=".\Hospitillity.App.Server.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="true"      // <<< MAKE THIS true
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            hostingModel="inprocess">
```

Note, the setting stdoutLogEnabled="true".  This will cause your hosting provider to generate log files.

Then recycle your app pool on your hosting provider.

Connect to your website again, and after the error you should have some more details about error logged in

```
\logs\stdout_nnnnnnnnnnnnnn_nnnnnn.log
```

on the hosting server.

Take it from there ...